# Progress messages - user experience

Tags: progress-bar, user-experience

When displaying progress bars do you display generic messages, such as:

- "Working"
- "Loading"
- "In Progress"

Or is the additional coding effort worth the user experience improvements resulting from more granular messages, such as

- "Loading Case 2 of 5"
- "Loading Teams"
- "Saving POL10283"

ALso, If you code granular messages, do you control these from teh objects to which they pertain, or to a wider view / module into which the objects are loading?

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes a significant improvement in usability if you message gives the user an idea of how much time left until the task if finished.

So something like "Processing item 2 of 5" is definitely better than just "Processing".

I also recommend to avoid progress bars than run up until then end then simply start again and again and again. That's only for teasing users. It feels like: "It'll be done in a minute. Well, maybe in one more minute. In a minute more".

Comment: I agree that displaying more accurate info to the users must by its very nature improve UX.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a task that you do not know the length of (No counts or loops to count) then a generic message or info ion the specific step is fine, but I do tend to try the percentage completed or "Case 2 of 5".

This gives a better indication of the actual task being performed.

Comment: Generally the length will not be known unless the effort to write code to establish the length is written. This is the crux of the question. Is this effort worth-while?

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating the "worth" is pretty difficult. Speaking as a user, I **really** like to know what's happening. Hence I tend to try to implement such detail.

I would decouple View from the actual processing detail (which may involve objects that the View really shouldn't know about) and use a kind of NoticeBoard in my model. Interesting events can be posted there, and the view can pick them up.

Comment: +1 I like the idea of a centralised notice board - like a status fields at the bottom left of many traditional windows apps.

Answer (score 0):

The feedback you get from the second option can be invaluable in tracking down unforseen bugs. In terms of which option to choose I would go for the second as it enables me to give the wider view a seperate thread. So, if the objects fail loading at least I have a general purpose mechanism to react to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

(1) I believe users would prefer more granular messages, in general.
However, you need to do a more detailed task analysis. You need to ask: How important is each task to them, each step in a task to them?

"Loading Case 2 of 5"
"Loading Teams" 
"Saving POL10283"
etc are fine in a chemical plant etc.

But in a simple app, they may not be that important.

(2) Concerning Question 2, I agree with djna above. The messages should be in the (business/domain) object. Their caller/client (usually controller or view/presentation) should get them from the objects.

Comment: Please stop tagging your posts with links to your site. That's mot appropriate on Stack Exchange sites.